# check if list of dates is within a date range in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, date-range

There are three main columns to my data shown below (`squirrel_id` = unique individual id, `byear` = year of birth, and `dyear` = year of death):

```
> summary(complete)
  squirrel_id        byear          dyear     
 Min.   :  416   Min.   :1989   Min.   :1989  
 1st Qu.: 4152   1st Qu.:1997   1st Qu.:1998  
 Median : 7870   Median :2003   Median :2004  
 Mean   :10419   Mean   :2004   Mean   :2004  
 3rd Qu.:16126   3rd Qu.:2011   3rd Qu.:2012  
 Max.   :23327   Max.   :2017   Max.   :2017
```

I have a second piece of data (shown below) that I am trying to incorporate into the above dataset.

```
mast.yr<-c("1993", "1998", "2005", "2010", "2014")
```

**I am trying to do two things:**

1. Add a column that says if the individual (`squirrel_id`) was alive during any of the `mast.yr` years (`dyear`- `byear` = range of years alive (including `byear` and `dyear`).
2. Add another column that counts how many `mast.yr` years each individual (`squirrel_id`) experienced during lifetime (`dyear`- `byear` = range of years alive (including `byear` and `dyear`).

To generate the first column, I've been using the `mutate` function in the `dplyr` package, but I can only get it to work for the `byear` and `dyear` separately, like so:

```
complete <- complete %>%
    mutate (mast = ifelse (byear %in% c("1993", "1998", "2005", "2010", "2014"), 1, 0), 
    mast = ifelse (dyear %in% c("1993", "1998", "2005", "2010", "2014"), 1, 0)))
```

But it doesn't give the desired output since it is considering the `byear` and `dyear` on their own, rather than as a continuous time period. I have tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310237/checking-if-dates-are-between-a-range) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716187/r-check-if-string-contains-dates-within-specific-date-range), but have had no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

A copy of my data can be found [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d). For reproducibility in the future, here is a sample:

```
> head(DF)

> squirrel_id  byear dyear
  <dbl>        <int> <dbl>
  6715         2006  2006
  22274        2016  2017
  20445        2014  2017
  19528        2013  2013
  2674         1995  1995
  1419         1992  1993
```

Comment: try using the `lubridate` package. Check out the interval section here: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# put target years in a table
mastDF = data_frame(year = as.integer(mast.yr))

# count based on conditions    
dat %>% 
  mutate(in_mast = count_matches(., mastDF, year >= byear, year <= dyear) > 0) %>%
  as.tbl

# A tibble: 100 x 4
   squirrel_id byear dyear in_mast
         <int> <int> <int>   <lgl>
 1        6715  2006  2006   FALSE
 2       22274  2016  2017   FALSE
 3       20445  2014  2017    TRUE
 4       19528  2013  2013   FALSE
 5        2674  1995  1995   FALSE
 6        1419  1992  1992   FALSE
 7       15014  2004  2004   FALSE
 8       10946  2009  2012    TRUE
 9        4369  1998  1999    TRUE
10        4344  1992  1999    TRUE
# ... with 90 more rows
```

where `count_matches` is a helper function:

```
library(data.table)
count_matches = function(DF, targetDF, ...){
  onexpr = substitute(list(...))
  data.table(targetDF)[data.table(DF), on=eval(onexpr), allow.cart=TRUE, .N, by=.EACHI]$N
}
```

---

If you want both the count and whether the count is non-zero, this can be done by breaking it into a sequence of `mutate` arguments:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    n_mast = count_matches(., mastDF, year >= byear, year <= dyear),
    in_mast = n_mast > 0
) %>% as.tbl

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  squirrel_id byear dyear n_mast in_mast
        <int> <int> <int>  <int>   <lgl>
1        6715  2006  2006      0   FALSE
2       22274  2016  2017      0   FALSE
3       20445  2014  2017      1    TRUE
4       19528  2013  2013      0   FALSE
5        2674  1995  1995      0   FALSE
6        1419  1992  1993      1    TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Do you have any suggestions for how to add another column that counts how many `mast.yr` years each individual (`squirrel_id`) experienced during lifetime.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist Sure. The count_matches function returns that count initially. I've edited the post to demonstrate. If you're interested, I wrote some details for how the function works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140399/

Comment: Thanks for explaining that a bit more. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Though @Frank has already provided an elegant solution but `sqldf` provides easier ways for non-equii joins. Using `sqldf` solution can be as:

```
mast.yr<-c("1993", "1998", "2005", "2010", "2014")

mastDf <- data.frame(year = as.integer(mast.yr))


library(sqldf)


sqldf("select dat.*, IFNULL(Mast.inMast,0) as n_Mast, IFNULL(Mast.inMast,0) >0 as inMast
       from dat left outer join 
      (select *, count(squirrel_id) as inMast 
      from dat, mastDf 
      where mastDf.year between dat.byear AND dat.dyear
      group by squirrel_id) Mast on
      dat.squirrel_id = Mast.squirrel_id")

#     squirrel_id byear dyear n_Mast inMast
# 1          6715  2006  2006      0      0
# 2         22274  2016  2017      0      0
# 3         20445  2014  2017      1      1
# 4         19528  2013  2013      0      0
# 5          2674  1995  1995      0      0
# 6          1419  1992  1992      0      0
# 7         15014  2004  2004      0      0
# 8         10946  2009  2012      1      1
# 9          4369  1998  1999      1      1
# 10         4344  1992  1999      2      1
#....90 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Do you have any suggestions for how to add another column that counts how many `mast.yr` years each individual (`squirrel_id`) experienced during lifetime.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist Yes, you can easily do that. Just add `group by squirrel_id` and use `count`. I have updated solution to cover that.